Desktop animations don't working and my screen; refresh rate is 60Hz but normally its 144Hz
I can't change 60Hz to 144Hz
System Information
System:
  Host: ern-akkc Kernel: 6.8.0-39-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: Victus by HP Gaming Laptop 16-r0xxx
    v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: CND317314X
  Mobo: HP model: 8BBE v: 77.44 serial: PSHTTO3WVI1IP8 UEFI: Insyde v: F.20
    date: 04/29/2024
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 56.3 Wh (100.0%) condition: 56.3/70.1 Wh (80.3%)
CPU:
  Info: 14-core (6-mt/8-st) model: 13th Gen Intel Core i7-13700H bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP cache: L2: 11.5 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 605 min/max: 400/4800:5000:3700 cores: 1: 447 2: 400
    3: 400 4: 400 5: 401 6: 400 7: 401 8: 400 9: 400 10: 400 11: 400 12: 401
    13: 400 14: 400 15: 400 16: 400 17: 399 18: 2401 19: 2454 20: 401
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: N/A
  Device-2: NVIDIA AD106M [GeForce RTX 4070 Max-Q / Mobile] driver: nvidia
    v: 535.183.01
  Device-3: Luxvisions Innotech HP True Vision FHD Camera driver: uvcvideo
    type: USB
  Display: server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia dri: swrast gpu: nvidia
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,nvidia,swrast
    platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-39-generic status: kernel-api
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: ac:19:8e:97:8b:23
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    driver: r8169
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: 7c:4d:8f:bc:5a:5d
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX211 Bluetooth driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
    address: AC:19:8E:97:8B:27
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 185.09 GiB (19.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVL21T0HCLR-00BH1
    size: 953.87 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 936.79 GiB used: 185.08 GiB (19.8%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1.05 GiB used: 6.1 MiB (0.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4 GiB used: 1.66 GiB (41.4%) file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): cpu: 0 fan-2: 0
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est. available: 13.34 GiB used: 6.42 GiB (48.1%)
  Processes: 441 Uptime: 6h 28m Shell: Sudo inxi: 3.3.34




Does this help? https://medium.com/@luca4tini/guide-to-easily-enable-the-graphic-card-in-ubuntu-4a0b21625bec

No it didn't work
